# How to customize the formatter for the loggingConfiguration?

Tags: asp.net, logging, exception, enterprise-library

I am new to EnterpriseLibrary.Logging. In the web.config, under the loggingConfiguration, we have following formatters:

```
<formatters>
    <add name="Default Formatter" template="&#xA;Timestamp: {timestamp(local)}&#xA;&#xA;Message: {message}&#xA;&#xA;Category: {category}&#xA;&#xA;Priority: {priority}&#xA;&#xA;EventId: {eventid}&#xA;&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xA;&#xA;Title:{title}&#xA;&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xA;&#xA;Application Domain: {appDomain}&#xA;&#xA;Process Id: {processId}&#xA;&#xA;Process Name: {processName}&#xA;&#xA;Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}&#xA;&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}&#xA;&#xA;User Name: {userName}&#xA;&#xA; extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}&#xA;)}" 
             type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add name="DBA Formatter" template="&#xA;Timestamp: {timestamp(local)}&#xA;&#xA;Message: {message}&#xA;&#xA;Category: {category}&#xA;&#xA;Priority: {priority}&#xA;&#xA;EventId: {eventid}&#xA;&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xA;&#xA;Title:{title}&#xA;&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xA;&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}&#xA;)}" 
             type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</formatters>
```

In the code behind, we only set the message to the LogEntry. I wonder how the others parameters get set, for example the timestamp, category, priority, etc. I have added the username, but doesn’t work. Can anybody shed some light on me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the Microsoft article on those parameters:  [Configuring Formatters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664562%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx).  It discusses the various tokens you can insert in a formatter.

"Username" is not one of the pre-defined tokens.  But you can (probably) get around that with the ExtendedProperties property of the LogEntry:

```
 LogEntry le = new LogEntry();
 le.ExtendedProperties.Add("username", "jsmith");
```